# InvalidAuthenticationToken. Access token validation failure. Invalid audience

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using client credentials flow of OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant. I have given the necessary permission Calendars.ReadWrite in my Azure application, which is needed for the api endpoint 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events'. I am able to get the token from Servicenow using the api '/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token' and passing the scope as myappURI/.default. But while using the token for the posting an event using the api 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events' I get 'Code:InvalidAuthenticationToken. Message:Access token validation failure. Invalid audience' error. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send https://graph.microsoft.com/.default for the scope.

> **4. Get an access token:**
>
> You specify the pre-configured permissions by passing
> https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as the value for the scope
> parameter in the token request. See the scope parameter description in
> the token request below for details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was sending the ID Token instead of the Access Token.

> - ID tokens are meant to be read by the OAuth client.
> - Access tokens are meant to be read by the resource server.
> - ID tokens are JWTs. Access tokens can be JWTs but may also be a random string.
> - ID tokens should never be sent to an API. Access tokens should never be read by the client.

Source: https://oauth.net/id-tokens-vs-access-tokens/